# Local minimum implies global minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization

Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$ (or even smoother if that helps) with $n > 1$. Assume that $f$ has a local minimum in $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and no other stationary points. Is $x_0$ then automatically a global minimum? For $n=1$ this is true and easy to show (e.g. with Rolle's theorem)...
My intuition says the answer should be yes but I can't prove it.

Comment: Possible answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121326/unique-critical-point-does-not-imply-global-maximum-global-minimum?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496321/if-a-function-of-two-variables-has-a-unique-critical-point-which-is-a-local-max). It also seems [Ted Shifrins multivariable calculus book goes through a similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987955/textbook-for-3d-geometry-with-analysis-point-of-view).