# Can this statement about the absolute extrema of a multivariable function be proven/disproven?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let there be a function $f(x,y)$ defined and differentiable on the open set $(-\infty..\infty,-\infty..\infty)$ which has exactly one point $(a,b)$ such that $\nabla f(a,b)$ is the zero vector, and which has a positive Hessian determinant at $(a,b)$. Then $(a,b)$ is an absolute extrema of $f$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html

Comment: I realize that. The question is concerning absolute extrema, not relative extrema.

Comment: What you usually do to find absolute extrema? You compare between all values at local extremas and also values at boundaries. Conclude.

Comment: When the region is unbounded, how do you accomplish this?

Comment: when the region is unbounded you may have no global extrema

Comment: Following Robert's comment on my answer. Do you mean exactly one point with gradient equal to zero OR exactly one point with gradient equal to zero AND Hessian definite (positive or negative)?

Comment: The latter. The Hessian determinant is positive so (a,b) cannot be a saddle point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=x^2 + y^2 (1 - x)^3$
$$f_x=2 x - 3 (1 - x)^2 y^2==0$$
$$f_y=2 (1 - x)^3 y$$
the only point where the gradient is vanishes is at $(0,0)$

$$f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2=6 x^2 y + 2 (1 - x^3) (2 - 6 x y^2)\underset{x=0=y}{=}4>0$$
We have minimum there since
$$f_{xx}=2 - 6 x y^2\underset{x=0=y}{=}2>0$$
However, $f(0,0)=0$ and $f(5,1)=-39$ therefore the minimum is local.

Answer (score 0):

You can find counterexamples to your assumption.

Note $$
\Psi(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}} & \text{ for } \vert x \vert < 1\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ the [bump function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Now take the function $$f(x,y)=x +10\Psi(x)\Psi(y).$$

You can prove that $f$ has no absolute extrema, as $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x,0)=+\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} f(x,0)=-\infty$.

However $f$ has a local maximum at $(0,0)$.

Comment: This is wrong in two ways:  There are two critical points, and $(0,0)$ is not one of them.

Comment: @Robert. You're right. I have to modify the example. However, my understanding of the OP is that there is exactly one point $(a,b)$ with gradient equal to $0$ and Hessian definite (positive or negative), vs. exactly one critical point. Such example seems possible to create or do you have even doubt with this?

Comment: I'm getting four critical points. $(2.37854,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(.898237,0)$, and $(.331236,0)$

Comment: Nevermind. It is a piecewise so only the last two would apply.

Comment: There are examples with only one critical point, that critical point being a local max, but no global max.

Comment: I believe I can visualize this idea. Do you know of any function which would fit the criteria?

Comment: See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121326/unique-critical-point-does-not-imply-global-maximum-global-minimum